# Convert mysql binary to postgresql bytea

Tags: mysql, postgresql, data-structures

What is the easiest way to export data from mysql and import it in postgresql?

I am having trouble with the MySQL  binary fields conversion.

Comment: already answered at [How to migrate large blob table from mysql to postgresql?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4211)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of `binary` type in MySQL is `bytea` in PostgreSQL.

---

**You can use [pgloader](http://pgloader.io) (simplest way)**

After installing pgloader, create simple script `test.load`

```
load database  
from mysql://username:password@host/database_name
into postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/database_name

WITH include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences

  SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB',
      work_mem to '12MB'

 CAST type binary TO bytea drop typemod  using byte-vector-to-bytea;
```

Run it in your terminal:

```
pgloader test.load
```

---

**Another way is using `mysqldump`**

**1. Dump it with hex-blob option**

```
mysqldump -u username -p -h host --skip-quote-names --hex-blob --skip-triggers \
--compact --no-create-info your_db your_table > prepg.dump
```

**2. Do sed so it can be inserted to you `bytea` type column**

```
sed "s/0x\([0-9A-F]*\)/decode('\1','hex')/g" prepg.dump > pg.dump
```

**3. Load into your PostgreSQL table**

```
\i '/path_to_file/pg.dump'
```

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/how-to-migrate-large-blob-table-from-mysql-to-postgresql)